# How to access the view display's field list in row plugin options

Tags: views

I am trying to create a row plugin that would be similar to the [plugin](http://drupalcode.org/project/date_ical.git/blob_plain/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/date_ical_plugin_row_ical_feed.inc) in [date_ical](http://drupal.org/project/date_ical). The difference would be that it wouldnt use the entity display but the fields defined in the view, thus allowing for example to place information from related entities.
To do this I would need to setup options in the options_form where i would select form the defined fields whih is the title and so on. Somehow i cant access the information about the defined fields. I keep searching the $this->view object and around, but cant find it :(. I am sure it has to be there. Please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found `$this->display->handler->get_field_labels();` in [views_plugin_style.inc](http://drupalcode.org/project/views.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-3.x:/plugins/views_plugin_style.inc#l190) and it seems to do the trick.